# How do you add a service to Program.cs using EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ef-core-6.0

In EF Core 6 they have combined the Startup.cs and Program.cs files into just Program.cs.
I followed the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0
and added `builder.Services.AddScoped<IMovieService, MovieService>();`
to my Program.cs file but I get this:

`System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: movie_library.core.Services.IMovieService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: movie_library.core.MovieService': Unable to resolve service for type 'movie_library.data.MovieLibraryContext' while attempting to activate 'movie_library.core.MovieService'.)'

I'm just trying to call my service in my api controller using dependency injection.
My Controller:

[image]

My Program.cs File:

[image]

Comment: Seems you have a MovieLibraryContext in the constructor for MovieService

Comment: They didn't combine Program.cs and Startup.cs in EF Core 6. EF Core has nothing to do with how you organize your code, so that's really tangential to your question. Newer versions of Visual Studio and the dotnet templates utilize a combined Program.cs and Startup.cs, but that's got nothing to do with EF Core.

Comment: The error you got is pretty clear: you didn't register EF with the DI container, so it doesn't know how to resolve the dependencies of your MovieService. Since your issue is related to how you register your services, you should show the relevant service registration code in the question.

Comment: Since all the documentation has been revised to the new top level program style, with new host builder helper methods. Everyone assumes that the old style `CreateHostBuilder` ... `UseStartup<..>` template doesn't work anymore. But nothing has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need something like this:

```
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieDatabase");


        services.AddDbContextFactory<MovieLibraryContext >(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

But it's hard to tell exactly without seeing your MovieService.